# how to make the y-axis value in order when using ggplot2 in R language

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science

I was trying to use ggplot2 to plot multiple lines in a window. this is my code here:

```
ggplot(type1_age, aes(x = Year, y = Value, group = Age, color = Age)) + geom_line()+ggtitle('The percentage distribution of type1 diabetes patients in different age groups')+ylab("percentage (%)")
```

type1_age file looks like this:
[image]
the result figure is this:
[image]

the problem is that y-axis in the result figure is not in order. can you please help me to figure out? Thanks!

Comment: From your image I would guess that you `Value` column is a character or a factor. Try with `ggplot(type1_age, aes(x = Year, y = as.numeric(Value), group = Age, color = Age))`

Comment: I think @stefan is on the right start, I suggest that it should be fixed in the data itself, not in the call to `ggplot2`: if you're plotting it numerically, you are likely to be doing something else numerically as well, so just do it once and don't deal with converting every time you want to do something with it. FYI, if `is.factor(Value)` is true, then `as.numeric(Value)` will return the numeric conversion of the integer indices, not the values themselves. See the difference between `as.numeric(factor(c("10","1")))` and `as.numeric(as.character(factor(c("10","1"))))`.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: hi, i tried as.numeric(Value) function. it worked. but the y-axis just show value of 0, 20 and 40. do you know how to show more values on the y-axis? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this (with tidyverse):

```
type1_age %>%
mutate(Value = Value %>% as.character %>% as.numeric) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Value, group = Age, color = Age)) +
geom_line()+
ggtitle('The percentage distribution of type1 diabetes patients in different age groups')+
ylab("percentage (%)")
```

I suspect you Value variable to be a character vector and not a numeric one. The first part of the code should transform it in one.

Tell me if it works!

Comment: hi, when i run the first two lines, the terminal reports that : Error in `ggplot()`:
! Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. can you please help me to resolve it? thanks!

Comment: Did you copy paste all of the code? Why run only two lines? It should be run all together. The mapping of the code is in the third line. if you want more help, I am going to need the dput of your dataframe.

Comment: sry i just past first two lines previously. now it worked. thanks! and i have one more question: now my y-axis value is just 0 , 20 and 40. can you please help me show all y values on the y-axis? thanks!

Comment: look at the scale_y_continuous() function